# SVG unionize Paths to achieve outer stroke

Tags: python, svg

I am trying to merge two svg paths to one path. The usual approach, just adding the `d` values together would result a path which, when i append a stroke will result the same strokes as if I didn't merge the paths.

Simplified Example:
[Original Two Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTprB.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHWWV.png)

My real paths do contain CubicBezier functions and I need to write the code in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A posible solution would be using a filter  to outline the 2 shapes like in the following example:

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg stroke="black" fill="silver">
  <g filter="url(#outline-red)">
  <path d="M10 10v100h200Z" id="p"/>
  <use href="#p" x="10" y="20"/>
  </g>

<filter id="outline-red">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="red" result="rd" />
<feComposite in ="rd" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
    
</svg>
```

Yet another option would be using a double thickness border and mask the group with the 2 shapes with itselfs like in the following example:

```css
svg{border:solid;}
```

```html
<svg >
  <defs>
  <g id="g">
  <path d="M10 10v100h200Z" id="p"/>
  <use href="#p" x="10" y="20"/>
  </g>
    <mask id="m">
      <rect width="300" height="150" fill="white"/>
      <use href="#g" />
    </mask>
 </defs> 
  
  
  <use href="#g" stroke="red" stroke-width="8" mask="url(#m)" />
    
</svg>
```

Comment: Really nice approach, works perfectly. Thanks a lot!